# SQL Server Management Studio crashes when attaching a database

Tags: ssms

I can't attach my database with SSMS, it keeps crashing [image: crash]

I could not find any fixes anywhere so I'll try my luck here. It does not provide any errors. This just happened after Windows updated.

**UPDATE**

Here are my logs:

Not sure if this is the error itself but the time is correct

> 2016-01-19 02:35:57.95 spid24s     The Service Broker endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
>   2016-01-19 02:35:57.95 spid24s     The Database Mirroring endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
>   2016-01-19 02:35:58.00 spid24s     Service Broker manager has started.
>   2016-01-19 02:35:58.00 spid8s      Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
>   2016-01-19 02:35:58.05 Server      Software Usage Metrics is disabled.
>   2016-01-19 02:39:18.89 spid55      Attempting to load library 'xpsqlbot.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
>   2016-01-19 02:39:18.91 spid55      Using 'xpsqlbot.dll' version '2014.120.2000' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_qv'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
>   2016-01-19 02:39:26.03 spid56      Attempting to load library 'xpstar.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
>   2016-01-19 02:39:26.05 spid56      Using 'xpstar.dll' version '2014.120.2000' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_instance_regread'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.

Comment: Try rolling back the Windows Update and see if you can attach your DB now. If it doesn't, try a reinstall of SSMS. Also, try to run SSMS in Administrator mode.

Comment: @Batuta I tried those but it did not resolve the problem.

Comment: Can you provide some snippets on your log files, to ascertain what's causing for SSMS to crash?

Comment: @Batuta I've updated my question

Comment: Have you tried to use another machine with a working SSMS? Try to attach your DB on that machine and see how it goes. It's likely the Windows Update corrupted something on your machine. Hard to tell with very minimal capability to debug from here.